# Sympy deadlock / infinite hanging when trying to invert a 24x24 matrix

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, sympy, matrix-multiplication

I have the following 24x24 square matrix, H,  that has a non 0 determinent:

```
Matrix([
[ 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -R5, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  1.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -R4,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -R11, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, -R9, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, -R7,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -R10, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, -R8, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, -R6,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  -R3,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  -R2,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  -R1,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  -R0],
[-1.0,  0.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[-1.0,  0.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0, -1.0],
[ 0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0]])
```

Whenever I try to compute H.inv() to obtain the inverse of the matrix, python just hangs infinitely. It does not crash, nor return an error.

using sympy.inverse(H) returns H**-1 (as in it returns the full uninverted matrix and adds **-1 on the end), but if I then try to multiply this matrix by another matrix, e.g, a column vector, I get the same infinite hanging again.

What is the cause of this? Can sympy just not handle matrices this large or is there something wrong with the original matrix H?

Comment: @JohanC Yes I did try with integers and recevied the same result. I'm assuming it is because of the algebraic terms in the matrix, is this just too much computation for smypy / python to handle?

Comment: @JohanC I left the instance running for 12 hours over night to clarify it was indeed a hang and not just taking a long time. My CPU is reasonlably fast (9700k @ 4.5GHz), so I assumed if it didn't complete it in 12 hours it never would. I have tried with similar smaller matrices which worked fine and also computed in a relatively short space of time (< 1 minute), I also tried a 24x24 identity matrix which computed almost instantly, hence why I believe the algebraic terms to be the cause here. This post was to determine if it's a limitation and not an error with the matrix.

Comment: Is it possjble to estimate tbe size of the denominator, the determinant?  In the answer I see many terms that are size 4 combinations of the 12 symbols.  In a numeric solution these reduce one number, but in this symbolic version this gets larger with matrix shape and symbol number.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the inverse of a matrix like this will get much faster in SymPy soon. I have an implementation that can invert this in 24 seconds but that can also be improved. As suggested in the comments the new implementation is generally faster with integer/rational than float.

It takes a long time partly because sympy can be made more efficient but also because the answer is complicated even if the matrix itself looks simple. In fact I just tried to post the answer here but SO said

```
Body is limited to 30000 chars; you entered 2691249
```

so it is too complicated to show here.

Instead I'll just show the upper-left entry of the inverse matrix:

```
In [23]: ok[0, 0]
Out[23]: 
                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
R₀⋅R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₂⋅R₅ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₂⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₄⋅R₅ 

                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
+ R₀⋅R₁⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₅⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₅⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₅ + R₀⋅R

                                                                                        R₀⋅R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₂
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₄⋅R₅ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₅⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₅⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅

⋅R₃ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₂⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₉ + R₀
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
R₈ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₅ + R₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₂⋅R₅⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₂

⋅R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₀⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₅ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₅⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₅⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₄⋅R₅⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₅⋅R

₃⋅R₇ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₂⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₃
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₇⋅R₈ + R₀⋅R₅⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₄ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₆ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₇ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₆ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R

⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₃⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₀⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₄ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₆ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₇ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₆ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₈ + 
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₆ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₄⋅R₅ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₅⋅R₆ + 

R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₁₁⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₆ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₆⋅R₉ 
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
R₁⋅R₂⋅R₅⋅R₇ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₅⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₅⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁

+ R₁⋅R₂⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₂⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₃⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₉ + 
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅R₃⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₄⋅R₅⋅R₆ + R₁⋅R₄⋅R₅⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₅⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁⋅R₅⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₅⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁⋅R₅⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₁⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅

R₁⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₄ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₉ 
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₄ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₇⋅R₈ + 

+ R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₁
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
R₁₀⋅R₁₁⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₄⋅R₅ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₅⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₅⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R

₀⋅R₂⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₇⋅R
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₂⋅R₅⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₅⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₂⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₃⋅R₈⋅R

₈⋅R₉ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₆ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₆⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆ +
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₉ + R₁₀⋅R₄⋅R₅⋅R₆ + R₁₀⋅R₄⋅R₅⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₅⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁₀⋅R₅⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₅⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₀⋅R₅⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₁₀⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁

 R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₆ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₃⋅R₉ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₆⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₂⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R

₆⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₆⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₈ + R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₄⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₃⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₁₁⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₁₁⋅R₆⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₅ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₄⋅R₉ + R₂

R₉ + R₃⋅R₆⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₄⋅R₆⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₆⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉                                                                                                  
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
⋅R₃⋅R₅⋅R₆ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₅⋅R₇ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₅⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₅⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R₃⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₄⋅R₅⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₅⋅R₆⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R

                                                                                                                                                            
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
₅⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₂⋅R₅⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₆⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₂⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₄⋅R₅⋅R₆ + R₃⋅R₄⋅R₅⋅R₈ + R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₈ + R₃⋅R₄⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₄⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₅⋅R₆⋅R₇ + R₃⋅R₅⋅R₆⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₅⋅

                                                                                                                                                 
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
R₇⋅R₈ + R₃⋅R₅⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₃⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₆⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₃⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₄⋅R₅⋅R₆⋅R₈ + R₄⋅R₆⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₅⋅R₆⋅R₇⋅R₈ + R₅⋅R₆⋅R₈⋅R₉ + R₆⋅R₇⋅R₈⋅R₉
```

Comment: Wow. Would it be simpler to output if common subexpressions would be stored in separate variables? Or would there be too many subexpressions to be manageable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is very interesting to know. May I ask, are you in anyway actively involved with the development of SymPy? I ask as origin of my question comes from part of my thesis I am currently writing as part of my reserach and this would be a useful reference to add

Comment: I am a maintainer of sympy. I just posted the code used for this on github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21834

Comment: I'm not sure how many common subexpressions there are but the implementation I used for this uses the sparse multivariate polynomial representation so it is different from ordinary sympy expressions. The current Matrix.inv method uses ordinary sympy expressions which have a tree representation and is slower partly as a result of that. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/domainsintro.html#sparse-polynomial-representation